# C++ map with pointer as key. Memory management

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, stdmap

I've an STL like implementation of a map with pointer as keys. As I noticed the keys won't get freed by the map. Because I cannot keep references to all pointers I can not manage the memory myself. I read something about smart pointers raising two questions:

1. Is there another way to get auto memory management except of using
   smart pointer?
2. Will smart pointer like Boosts Smart Pointer will free my memory when the key is not longer present, or overridden by another pointer in the map?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why are you using pointers for keys?  what are you trying to do?

Comment: If you want the memory free'd when the key is no longer present in the map (i.e. the map being responsible for the memory of its keys....), what are the pointers for?

Comment: Usually the value will be the thing you would need to delete and not the key. What is the value?

Comment: @NeilKirk The key is an unsigned char array, allocated with malloc. The value is simply an integer.

Comment: That's bad. Use `std::vector` or `std::array` and a custom comparator.

Comment: But the memory usage of those objects is higher than my array. I've approx. 1,6 billion entries and that could cause immense memory problems when the size of the key increases.

Comment: @aQuip you can provide custom "deleter" for a smart pointer. If you really have to use `malloc()` then just put `free()` as a custom deleter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use smart pointer as a key in a `std::map` without custom comparator, then it does not work, as you simply would not replace one object with another, as pointer to one object is not equivalent to another and replace would not occur. If you do use comparator then it still would not work automatically, as key is a constant and only value modified when you replace item in a map. So I think you have 3 ways to fix your issue (assuming you do use custom comparator):

1. Still use `std::map` but when replacing element remove previous key/value pair first and insert new pair, do not use operator[] or assignment to `iterator->second`
2. Still use `std::map` but keep smart pointer and data in `value` part and copy key from your object.
3. Use different container, for example Boost.Multi-index. You may not need multiple indexes but this container allows using part of object as a key and `replace` method.

Comment: 1. I've high performance requirements and I think looking for the key in the map and replace afterwards will cause problems.
2. What do you mean with `copy key from your object`.
3. I'm already using a library called `b-tree` but it's implementing the STL-interface and I cannot change the container.

Comment: @aQuip you have to look for a key to replace an element no matter what. But removing and readding element may definatelly have price. Then either use 2 or 3

Comment: Can you please explain what benefits I have when using a key from the value-object.

Comment: Let's say you object hast `std::string name` and use it as key for comparator. Solution 2 would be to use `std::string` as a key for the `std::map` and copy `name` to the key on object insertion. For Boost.Multiindex `name` field would be the key, and you will not need explicit code to copy `name` into key, so at least less verbose code and less possibility for bugs.

Comment: Okay that makes sense but my value is only an int holding a price. The key is a binary representation of a keystring and has nothing to do with the price. That is why I would not like to create an object with the price and the `key`, which would be only in the object for this purpose. Why is it a problem to give the map a pointer to the location of the char array?

Comment: @aQuip it is not a problem for the map, it is problem for you. You want object, pointed by smart pointer replaced if I understand you correctly. `std::map` does not modify keys, that's the way it works, so if you have smart pointer as a key, then it will not be replaced. You either work around  it or use different container.

Comment: No I do not want to replace the key. The value (price) should be replaced if the same key occurs twice.

Comment: Then I misunderstood your question. If you use smart pointer then objects will be destroyed when keys are destroyed, either you remove key from the map or destroy whole map.

Comment: @aQuip the reason of my misunderstanding is your statement "overridden by another pointer in the map". This is not possible unless... see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. In C++11 smart pointers is the only auto memory management.
2. Yes, std::shared_ptr will delete the memory when the last reference to the key is removed.

You should use strings instead of dynamically allocated char arrays. Strings is auto managed memory. It won't be convenient to use shared_ptr with dynamically allocated arrays of chars. A shared_ptr is good to manage objects.

Comment: It will actually call the destructor, so you have to make sure that there is a good one.

Comment: _`std::smart_ptr`_ Uhm, what? You probably meant `std::shared_ptr`

Comment: Can you please provide a simple example of using smart pointer with dynamically allocated char array?

Comment: @aQuip smart pointer with dynamically allocated char array is a smart pointer to `std::vector<char>` or just `std::string`

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the keys are something in the object that your pointers point to and not the pointers themselves.  If so, and you don't want to use smart pointers for whatever reason, when you erase a map element, delete the object.  And don't forget to delete them all when the map is freed.  And don't forget to handle copy constructor and assignment operator etc.